# nodejs express modify another user session variable

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm storing some kind of information as a session variable in my nodejs app.
the problem is some times i want to modify another user(session) variable which i could not access it via

```
variable= req.session.myvariable
```

I'm looking for a way to access special user variable. something like this:

```
variable= req.session("user01").variable
```

is this possible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation:

```
req.session[variable] = "blah"
```

Comment: No I mean another user session not current session variable

Comment: @maximax, uh, I'm thinking it's a terrible idea to allow one user to get session data from another. Just imagine the security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Mulan When an administrator defines, for example, a permission level for a user, and wants it to apply immediately without logging out and logging in again. Is this not a legitimate case?

Comment: not a simple problem.. a strategy of "they only need to be read when the user logs in" begets a category of "the user's permissions are stale" problems, and a category of solutions to those problems. an effective strategy i've seen is to perform permission reads in tandem with sensitive actions, such as executing a financial transaction, deleting a project resource, granting permissions to others. Less sensitive actions like fetch current notifications, fetch profile can rely on a cached permission.